# Browser freezes frequently. Will it be a swap problem?

Tags: freeze, swap, browser

I am facing a problem with very slow browser apps, Wine games and Unity. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on my Sandisk Cruzer 32GB flash drive.

I have N53SV Laptop with 16 GB RAM and an nVidia card, and switching with my Intel one works fine, I've recently updated my nVidia with CUDA, but the main problem from  the beginning is the swap. I've read many posts, that say to aviod using swap. (like [this one](http://fosswire.com/post/2009/02/sysctl-swappiness/)).

Is there any way to tweak my system and make read and write speeds faster and run games and apps without freezes and hangs.

My last question is: in a modern OS, is it important to create and use swap?

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely not a swap problem, with 16 GB of RAM, it is quite unlikely that you run out of it. USB pendrives are simply not fast enough for this workload. Why don't you install the OS on a disk?

And regarding the swap question. AFAIK use of a swap has nothing to do with how modern an operating system is. The question is, do you need a swap for your workload or not. With 16GB, I would say, you most likely do not.

Comment: But, as it is a laptop, you can not use hibernate or sleep without SWAP, as the system transfers all data from RAM to Swap to re-load when it wakes up again.

Comment: You can use suspend without a swap partiton (if your CPU supports S3 state), but yes hibernation needs a swap partition.